# Changing the "Top Questions" text

Tags: discussion

Wouldn't recent questions be a better name for the default view?

After all, these are not the top questions in any sense other than they were recently edited/answered.

Answer (score 1):

That list order the questions basing also on how recently an existing answer has been edited, not only basing on the recently edited, or answered questions.

To me "recent questions" would mean the recently asked questions, which is more reductive than the actual list being shown.

It makes sense to call the list "top questions" because the list shows a very limited set of questions; the page doesn't even have a pager.

Comment: Top makes it seem that the list is "better" than it is. Perhaps something like "recently updated" would be better?

Comment: _Top questions_ just means _the first X questions_; it doesn't imply some questions are better than others. If the questions were ordered per received votes, then the top questions would be the questions with higher votes, but that still doesn't imply those questions are better than others; it just means they have more votes than other questions.

Answer (score 0):

I agree.

Sure, we all know that "top" refers to the *recency* rather than the *quality* of the questions, but how would new visitors know that? Considering how the [the phrase "*top questions*" is commonly used](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=top+questions&fp=1) it is indeed possible that the title may be misconstrued to mean a list of featured questions.

In other words, it's not down to whether we know what it means -- most of us visit so often we almost never see the title anyway -- it's what a new visitor sees and takes from it.

Imagine you're on a site you know nothing about; what's your first assumption about the list when greeted with the following?

[image: Is that the best you can offer?]

Indeed an observant person would eventually deduce that those questions aren't exactly the cream of the crop, but if visitors had work it out themselves then the title isn't really doing its job.